# xubuntu windows manager does not keep settings

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager

It's a great feature in Xfce that allows you to keep other windows visible while typing in a window that's underneath. The only issue is that every time the system restarts or goes into sleep mode, the setting is lost. I find it a bit tedious to have to go to the window manager, navigate to the focus tab, and then check and uncheck the 'Raise window when clicking inside application window' checkbox again.

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: You will need to specify the Ubuntu (Xubuntu) version you are using. This rather appears as a bug, which then cannot be answered here, but should be reported. Note it could be related to your hardware or your setup only. With "restart", I suppose you mean restarting from hibernation or sleep state? A full restart will not remember windows unless "save session" is on, but that never worked well, is disabled by default in XFCE and removed since long in Gnome desktop.

Comment: My sYstem is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: This information belongs to your question, not in a comment. Use "edit" to add information that can be relevant to solve your question.